# DecryptSymmetric with triple DES errors

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

```
%%[
VAR @value, @dec, @email, @other, @null
SET @email = emailaddr
SET @null = 
SET @value = Lookup("Encrypted Jimmy Testing","EncrypText","emailAddress",@email)
SET @dec = Base64Decode(DecryptSymmetric(@value, 'tripledes', @null, 'TestKey', @null, @null, @null, @null))
]%%

Testing stuff<br />
%%=v(@email)=%%<br />
%%=v(@value)=%%<br />
%%=v(@dec)=%%<br />
```

I get the error: An error occurred when attempting to evaluate a DecryptSymmetric function call. See inner exception for details.

The encrypted string is: U2FsdGVkX184wRqUXjZxreLHvWAasKdGgp90k0oXRsXYIJ6ZAJnoEJUX9GcsSZUfUEd97FuDsLD67mNUBAUENA==

Comment: Please post the details about how the string was encrypted in the data extension.   Pretty sure all of the parameters after the password cannot be null.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you encrypted the data somehow that didn't use the `EncryptSymmetric()` function.  AMPScript's Symmetric Crypto functions are intended to only be used within the Marketing Cloud vs 3rd party encryption/decryption.  If you have a compelling reason to go down the road of using a symmetric encryption outside the MC environment there is a [**blog post**](https://web.archive.org/web/20160119035641/http://adventureswithet.com/2014/02/22/encryption-decryption-ampscript/) written by a partner that covers the topic.