# Encrypting/Encoding the link to Custom Preference Center

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am building a custom preference center and will be using its URL in the body of the emails.

Is there a way to encrypt that link so that it can't be intercepted? (like the standard profile center link)

Answer (score 0):

If the custom preference center is using a Marketing Cloud landing page then you can use the AMPScript functions EncryptSymmetric() and DecryptSymmetric().

https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/encryption/EncryptSymmetric.html

https://code.exacttarget.com/content-scripting/ampscript/encryption/DecryptSymmetric.html

Comment: It's not using Marketing Cloud Landing page 

Comment: The official line is that these two functions are not supported outside the platform, but [it can be done](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/84440/5202) with DES.