# EncryptSymmetric AMPScript AES

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, encryption

We want to encrypt / encode URL parameters on our pages. I tried to encrypt a parameter using [EncryptSymmetric()](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/encryptsymmetric/) with AES algorithm as explained in the [documentation](http://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/ampscript/ampscript_syntax_guide/utilities_ampscript_functions/encryptsymmetric/)

```
%%[SET @encData=EncryptSymmetric("test", "AES", @null, "1111", @null, "0000000000000000", @null, "00000000000000000000000000000000")
]%%
AES: %%=v(@encData)=%%
```

The result of this function is

> AT1r0irnzM+Ax1j8zN+zAw==

Then I tried to decrypt the value using an [online tool](http://aesencryption.net/), but I always received an error message.

I suppose there is a difference between AES algorithm in Marketing Cloud and AES used in the online tool. Indeed if I encrypt the same word with an online tool (128-bit), I received this result

> l4Yo3sFofFD1EMmtoh397w==

Do you have any deep information regarding this function? What could be the difference?

Comment: There are only certain types of SFMC encryption that you can decrypt outside of the platform.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this? Struggling with AES in the Marketing cloud as well right now.

Comment: Struggling with this as well but need to decrypt the string in C#. Anyone was able to accomplish that?

Answer (score 5):

I have decrypted SFMC encrypted strings in C# outside of the platform.  Credit for the method goes to [**Pato Sapir**](https://github.com/psapir) on Github for his [**et-encrypt-decrypt**](https://github.com/psapir/et-encrypt-decrypt) solution.

You should be able to decrypt the string outside of the platform with the code referenced above if you use parameters like this in your AMPScript:

```
%%=EncryptSymmetric("test","des;mode=ecb;padding=zeros",@null,"12345678")=%%
```

Also...props to [**@brandt**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/11147/brandt) for his answer, which is what lead me to psapir's solution:

[**DecryptSymmetric with tripe DES errors**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/84440/5202)

Comment: Thanks @Adam for the answer. However i would use the same algorythm used in Salesforce (where i have AES128, 192 and 256). But there is no matching with that used in Marketing Cloud.

Comment: @robertc SFMC is fussy about algorithms and particularly around padding, salt and Iv lengths, so you'll need get SF CRM to fit in around it, rather than the other way around.

Comment: Just saw this. Thanks @Adam and Eliot for noticing the post. more info here: http://www.devsutd.com/encryption-and-decryption-with-ampscript/

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to get it working with AES too

The trick is block size 16, key size 32, pbkdf2 with 1000 iterations and padding pkcs7

```python
import base64
from pprint import pprint
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES

from Cryptodome.Protocol.KDF import PBKDF2
from Cryptodome.Util.Padding import pad

data = b'Example'
password = b'password'
salt = bytes.fromhex('0000000000000000')
iv = bytes.fromhex('00000000000000000000000000000000')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    block_size = 16
    key_size = 32
    key = PBKDF2(password, salt, key_size)  # pbkdf2 defaults to 1000 iterations

    cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
    ct_bytes = cipher.encrypt(pad(data, block_size))  # pad defaults to pkcs7

    ct_b64 = base64.b64encode(ct_bytes).decode('utf-8')

    result = {
        'data': data.decode('utf-8'),
        'password': password.decode('utf-8'),
        'salt': salt.hex(),
        'iv': iv.hex(),
        'ciphertext': ct_b64,
    }
    print('Expected ciphertext: L2pjkUH92JSH4KyVY0jGxw==')
    pprint(result)
```

Comment: Please note that this answer demonstrates how to use AES which provides improved security characteristics  compared to DES and 3DES.

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/26179/security-comparsion-of-3des-and-aes

Comment: I was able to reproduce the expected ciphertext from the code example with this AmpScript

`SET @cipherText=EncryptSymmetric("Example", "aes;mode=cbc;padding=pkcs7", @null, "password", @null, "0000000000000000", @null, "00000000000000000000000000000000")`

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented two (Java and Kotlin) versions of the same solution, after struggling myself to find one online:

https://github.com/Osguima3/salesforce-compatible-aes

It uses the BouncyCastle library since the core java libraries don't support PKCS7

Answer (score 0):

this code in JS does return the same result as SFMC

```
    const password = 'PASSWORD';
    const salt = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('0000000000000000');   
    const iv = CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse('00000000000000000000000000000000');
  
    function encryptAES() {
    var value =  decodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("txtText").value);
    var key = buildKey(password, salt);
    var encryptedStringHex = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(value, buildKey(password, salt), {iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7}).toString();
    
    document.getElementById("txtEncryptedAES").value = encryptedStringHex.toString(); 
    }
    
    function decryptAES() {
  var valueEncrypted = decodeURIComponent(document.getElementById("txtEncryptedAES").value);
   var key = buildKey(password, salt);
    var decryptedStringHex = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(
     valueEncrypted, buildKey(password, salt), {iv: iv, mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7});
    document.getElementById("txtDecryptedAES").value = decryptedStringHex.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
    }

    function buildKey(password, salt) {
    var key = CryptoJS.PBKDF2(password, salt, {
      keySize: 256 / 32,
      iterations: 1000,
      hasher: CryptoJS.algo.SHA1
    });
    return key;
  }
```