# Can I pass an encrypted value as a URL parameter?

Tags: marketing-cloud, parameters, encryption

I'm looking to pass email address as an encrypted value (DES) to avoid PII in email links for compliance with Google remarketing.

I'm able to use the EncryptSymmetric in the email body to create a DES-encrypted value passed in a URL:

```
<!-- %%[
Var @encData

SET @encData=EncryptSymmetric(emailaddr, 'des', @null, '0x7FEBCBCBCB9BCB01', @null, @null, @null, @null)

]%% -->

<table id="Table_01" width="640" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <tbody><tr>
        <td>
            <a href="http://www.garnethill.com/womens-fashion/dresses/?ucv=%%=v(@encData)=%%" conversion="true" alias="0">This email link is encrypted</a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody></table>
```

But this method requires me to hard code `?ucv=%%=v(@encData)=%%` to the link.

I've tried passing the same variable `ucv=%%=v(@encData)=%%` in `_AdditionalEmailAttribute2` but the resulting link only includes `&ucv=` without pulling in the dynamic value. Can the
`_AdditionalEmailAttribute2` only look up a standard personalization string or a dynamic value in a data extension (as opposed to the body of the email sent)?

If this was sent using Web-Analytics Connector to use the dynamic variable (`ucv=%%=v(@encData)=%%`) would WAC correctly pick up the `@encData` from the email body?

Any other methods to accomplish DES encryption for email in a parameter?

Answer (score 2):

AMPScript variables will not get evaluated in the Additional Email Attributes, unfortunately.

Yes, you can include email variables in the WAC.

Decrypting SFMC content outside of the platform is tricky.

Here's one solution using AES: [**EncryptSimmetric AMPScript AES**](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/157898/5202)

Comment: Thanks Adam - I'll run this in WAC on a test account. We have an existing process in place to decrypt the DES value. Much appreciated!

Comment: DES decryption outside of SFMC?

Comment: Follow up on this issue: I had success passing an encrypted value to a WAC parameter value using Set @encData = EncryptSymmetric and putting a parameter for uid=@encData in WAC. We're continuing to have issues with getting the correct encrypted value - internally we use DES with mode ECB and padding PKCS5. It appears SFMC will only support PKCS7, and even attempts to send with PKCS7 resulted in an error at send. We're engaging an SOW to resolve the encryption.

Comment: I know it's possible to decrypt AES outside the platform.

Comment: Solved! I had a developer get into our test account and resolve the script issue. We're now able to encrypt the email using DES and pass the encrypted value in a parameter string using WAC. The final encryption string was not dependent on padding. I've created a shared content area to pickup the script for encrypt symmetric across our enterprise business units.

Comment: Do we have an equivalent method for EncryptSymmetric/Decrypt in SSJS? @AdamSpriggs

Comment: No, but you can certainly mix SSJS and AMPScript in the same page.