# Need Ampscript EncryptSymetric() output to match Coldfusion encrypt()

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, encryption, url-encode

I am trying to use ampscript in marketing cloud to produce an encrypted string that matches encryption on a coldfusion page. I do not have the ability to change the coldfusion encryption, so the challenge is getting the AMPScript output to match the coldfusion output exactly. Unfortunately I do not have much knowledge on encryption or on coldfusion, so hopefully someone can help. Maybe suggest an alternate approach that will achieve the same end result?

The coldfusion code is as follows:

```
<cfoutput>
<cfset start_string = 'testemail@testdomain.test' />
<cfset password_key = 'BCn+HS6a1u2=' />
<cfset email_encrypt = urlencodedformat(encrypt(start_string,password_key,'DES','Base64')) />
#email_encrypt#
</cfoutput>
```

**CF output:**
slmEJH3mDM9yTfymJ07m2QSV%2F%2FaTSm6AEAelELjjKpI%3D

Besides just encrypting, I also need to encode in Base 64 and then encode that for URL. I have not found an AMPScript function for URL encoding, so for the moment I just removed urlencodedformat().

**Now CF output:**
slmEJH3mDM9yTfymJ07m2QSV//aTSm6AEAelELjjKpI=

I have tried the following in AMPScript:

```
SET @emailencrypt = Base64Encode(EncryptSymmetric("testemail@testdomain.test","DES",@null,"BCn+HS6a1u2=", @null, @null, @null, @null))
```

**AMPScript output:**
Nm83VmxMYm9xd0Rpd2d5N2VNTWJUcC9EcCtvTENzVzZ0VUV4cjlUWlFPOD0=

It is the same string, encryption algorithm, password and encoding, but the output does not match. Not even the same length.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Could you try using a 16 byte hex string for the passphrase on both sides? Eg: "0x7FEBCBCBCB9BCB01".

Comment: Thanks @Macca but unfortunately I have no control over password_key value. (It is static on the CF server side.) The system is set up to to where a user enters an email address into a form and is sent an email with the encrypted email address as a parameter in a URL in the email. I am trying to bypass the coldfusion server altogether by creating the same link in marketing cloud.

Comment: There are too many variables and unknowns to suggest a solution in the platform for you.  The only example that I've seen that replicates the SFMC en/decryption was done in C#: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/157898/5202

Comment: @AdamSpriggs I'm not sure I understood your response. What I am trying to do is replicate a CF function in SFMC - not the other way around. I'm hoping that the CF function and output listed above are enough for someone with a better understanding of encryption and the AMPScript function to suggest what values to use for each argument to get the same result.

Comment: My point is that the only encryption interoperability I've seen is with C#, not CF.