# Apex Encryption to AMPscript Decryption

Tags: apex, marketing-cloud, ampscript, encryption, decrypt

I receive a string encrypted using the Apex function Crypto.encryptWithManagedIV() using AES256 as a url parameter, and I need to be able to decrypt this string on a marketing cloud landing page.

I have tried using the DecryptSymmetric() function, but I get an error saying "padding is invalid and cannot be removed".

The Apex code that generates the string is:

```
Blob cryptoKey = Blob.valueOf('I Am Thirty Two Bytes Long 12345');
Blob encryptedData = Crypto.encrypt('AES256', cryptoKey, Blob.valueOf('1234567890123456'), Blob.valueOf('Test123'));
String Output = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(encryptedData);
system.debug('Encrypted====== ' + Output);
```

The output of that code is:

```
Encrypted====== Crbyjxq+hJywMkfAky+SVw==
```

I have then taken that string and put it into the following AMPscript code to try and decrypt it:

```
%%[
set @string = "Crbyjxq+hJywMkfAky+SVw=="
/* Hex representation of 1234567890123456 */
set @iv = "31323334353637383930313233343536"

set @string = DecryptSymmetric(@string, "AES", @null, "I Am Thirty Two Bytes Long 12345", @null, "0", @null, @iv)
]%%
```

The padding used by the Apex method is pkcs5 and the default padding of the AMPscript method is pkcs7 which I have read should be compatible, so I do not understand the error message or what the problem is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Encrypting/decrypting between whatever and SFMC has been discussed multiple times around here.  The only working scenario I've seen is outlined here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/157898/5202

Comment: @Adam Spriggs that question is about decrypting AMPscript encryption in another system, mine is about the opposite, decrypting another system's encryption in AMPscript, of which I have seen very little discussion. If there was a relevant discussion on that, I would be grateful if you could point it out.

Comment: @ncv were you able to figure it out?

Comment: @user3276533 according to Salesforce Support, ampscript does not support decryption of data encrypted on other platforms, even if those other platforms are also owned by Salesforce. Which means there's probably something non-standard about how ampscript handles encryption that prevents this from working.

Comment: @ncv thank you for the reply. I probably have to go MD5 hashing then. Thanks!