# Hiding sensitive link data in url with AMP?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, preference-center

Having a problem when clicking the manage preferences link it cannot show the tracking or PII information (email address) in the browser. Have tried using Redirect and URLEncode to limit what shows up but having no luck.

What AMPscript function could create this type of link, "www.company.com/preferences" as the final outcome after being clicked?

Email Link = `www.company.com/preferences?email=%%emailadd%%&cmp_id=cmpid`

Display Link = `www.company.com/preferences?email=email@domain.com&cmp_id=1111111`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot fully "hide" parameters in your link, however, you can definitely encrypt your link via the [CloudPagesURL](https://ampscript.guide/cloudpagesurl/) function and since you would use it with the conjunction of UTM parameters, you gotta wrap it with [RedirectTo](https://ampscript.guide/redirectto/) function. Your link in the email would look something like this -

```
<!-- change 999 to the CloudPageID -->
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(999,'email',%%emailadd%%,'cmp_id',%%cmp_id%%))=%%">Link</a>
```

If it is not a CloudPage but an external website link, to which you still want to add parameters to pass and encrypt them, then you should take a look at those functions:

- [EncryptSymmetric](https://ampscript.guide/encryptsymmetric/) function
- [DecryptSymmetric](https://ampscript.guide/decryptsymmetric/) function
- and also a safer way of doing with [SHA512](https://ampscript.guide/sha512/) function

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. If I'm understanding correctly since it is going to an external website link will I need to modify the website with some decrypt function in order to have the url parameters hidden by a redirect?

Comment: In the email, you would have the EncryptSymmetric function and DecryptSymmetric function on the external website if you need to use the values you are passing as parameters, e.g. email address.

Comment: @niko - How do you expect OP being able to utilise DecryptSymmetric function outside of SFMC/CloudPages? Doing this, is not straightforward, as described here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/157734/encryptsymmetric-ampscript-aes I will indeed advise using hashing function instead, using HEM as an identifier in the URL, instead of plain text email address.