# Encrypt in Marketing Cloud - Decrypt in Salesforce

Tags: apex, marketing-cloud, encryption

I'm reading the documentation and I'm confused because functions in MC and SF have a different number of parameters (salt and password in MC, key in SFDC). Salesforce offers 3 versions of AES algorithms while in MC it's just AES. Has anyone had a successful experience of decrypting in Salesforce a value encrypted in Marketing Cloud?
I have tried passing password as key and vector to different versions of AES decrypt in SF (128,192,256), but it's complaining about key or vector length.

[This question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/157734/encryptsymmetric-ampscript-aes) has the answer on how to decrypt it outside of the platform in C# or python, but it's not applicable to Salesforce Apex. Solutions cannot be easily translated because they're not generic (i.e., technology-specific).

Comment: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/157734/encryptsymmetric-ampscript-aes has the details.

Comment: They managed to decrypt MC-enctypted strings in C# or python, I was asking about doing it in Salesforce

Comment: It works with AES. if you're stuck, please edit your question and put together a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Take a moment to read [How to Ask](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) and take the [tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found a solution.

MKCloud AMPScript's default AES implementation is based on a 256 bit key size, CBC with 16 byte block size, and PKCS7 with 1000 iterations.

The derived Key generation is based on **password** and **salt** with **PBKDF2, 1000 iteration, SHA-1 HMac function and 256 length.**

Crypto Class cannot generate the Key like AMPScript because the method **generateMac can not define the length** so HmacSHA1 return 20 bytes instead 32. crypto.generateMac('HmacSHA1', Blob.valueOf(salt), Blob.valueOf(key));

**SOLUTION**: Use the following tool to generate the key, store it in SF and use it to decrypt https://8gwifi.org/pbkdf.jsp

**Master Password** - (MKCloud) @password
**Salt (Base64)** - (MKCloud) @salt (Convert from hex to base64
https://base64.guru/converter/encode/hex)
**dkLen** - 256
**PBE Ciphers** - PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your answer @Jaume Bonet. Here's my code.

```
import crypto from 'crypto'; 
let password = 'anypasswordvalue';
let initVector = crypto.randomBytes(16); // 16 bytes (128 bits)
let salt = crypto.randomBytes(8); // 8 bytes (64 bits)

console.log('password: ' , password)
console.log('IV: ' , initVector.toString('hex'))
console.log('salt: ' , salt.toString('hex'))

let en = encryptAES('The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog! !@#$%^&*()_+', password, salt, initVector)
console.log('Encrypted Text: ' , en)

function encryptAES(data, password, salt, initVector) {
    // Generate key
    const key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, Buffer.from(salt, 'hex'), 1000, 32, 'sha1');

    // Create cipher
    const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, Buffer.from(initVector, 'hex'));

    // Encrypt data
    let encrypted = cipher.update(data, 'utf8', 'base64');
    encrypted += cipher.final('base64');

    return encrypted;
}
```

Ampscript:

```
outputline(concat(
        'Decoding: '
        , DecryptSymmetric('bfHMgljk/BpHudryDHranBLlEOZevJQvEH7Wj+nZxHNFYFHliBP+Bg9Esb61ZxiJ2AMRpGIknGaWPvvN1QIeUw==', "aes", @null, 'anypasswordvalue', @null, '701e6a98ec6e4f51', @null, 'c4a89623cbca32fa0a9d077569975fbc')
    ))
```